# animate background sprite jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Trying to animate a background sprite. After each strobe, jquery animates from y zero position. What do I need to do to tell jquery which frame position im on and animate from current y position.

```
function ttt(){
    document.getElementById('slidepngs').style.backgroundPosition=0+"px "+(yslide)+"px";
    setTimeout(pngslide,3000);
}

function pngslide(){
yslide+=284;

$('#slidepngs').animate({'background-position-x': '0','background-position-y': (yslide)},1000,'',ttt);


}
```